# Is there a scroll offset command in bash or PuTTY?

Tags: bash, putty

Is there a way to ensure that a certain number of lines (five, for example) will always appear above and below the cursor in bash? As I type command after command in PuTTY, the cursor and all my commands are at the very bottom. This can be frustrating if I'm sharing my screen with someone else, as they can't see the very bottom of the screen.

Comment: Try the answer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1106674/how-to-add-blank-lines-above-the-bottom-in-terminal) question.

Comment: "Unmaximize" the PuTTY window so the bottom of the screen is not occupied by it. Or use `tmux` with a bottom pane as a placeholder. Another possibility (on demand): [Reset bash prompt at the vertical middle of terminal window on double-enter](https://superuser.com/q/1503314/432690).

Answer (score 0):

From [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1106674/how-to-add-blank-lines-above-the-bottom-in-terminal) posted in the comment above:

```
PS1='\[\eD\eD\eD\e[A\e[A\e[A\]'
```

And then use pairs of "\eD" and "\e[A" for each line you want to scroll from the bottom. Brilliant!